# how to get the list of connected printer names using electron js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I'm building a desktop application using Electron JS and React JS. Here I need to fetch a list of connected Printers to Local Area Network. Can you please suggest me what will be the best way to do this with Electron and React.

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: I haven't tried yet.